# Como criar uma lista de múltiplos de 3, a partir de outra lista de números?

Tags: python, lista

```
meus_numeros = [1, 56, 342, 12, 781, 23, 43, 45, 123, 567]

for c in meus_numeros:
    if c%3 == 0:
    print(c, end='')
```

```
File "<ipython-input-12-2b3fd4ceddad>", line 3
    print(c, end='')
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: O `print` está identando no mesmo nível do `if`, é só arrumar a identação que funciona: https://ideone.com/T1wuoe - além disso, estou votando para fechar como "erro de digitação", seguindo o que foi definido aqui: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7476/112052

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar list comprehension, que irá te retornar uma nova lista com os múltiplos de 3:

```
meus_numeros = [1, 56, 342, 12, 781, 23, 43, 45, 123, 567]

nova_lista = [numero for numero in meus_numeros if numero % 3 == 0]
print(nova_lista)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a função `.append()`

`.append()` é um método que anexa um elemento ao final da lista. Logo, se você criar uma lista e usar `.append(c)`, ele irá adicionar o `c` ao final da lista.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
meus_numeros = [1, 56, 342, 12, 781, 23, 43, 45, 123, 567]
lista = []
for c in meus_numeros: 
    if c%3 == 0: 
        lista.append(c)
```

Comment: Printar uma lista não parece ser a vontade do autor da pergunta já que ele delcarou seu print como `print(c, end='')`

Comment: retirei o print

Answer (score 0):

Seu problema foi ter colocado o `print` fora do laço `if`.

Já que o valor da variável C é a condição para printar ou não a linha (se o número testado for um número divisível por três) e como este valor depende da comparação do `If`, seu print deve estar identado dentro do laço:

```
meus_numeros = [1, 56, 342, 12, 781, 23, 43, 45, 123, 567]

for c in meus_numeros:
    if c%3 == 0:
        print(c, end=' ')
```

P.S. Seu `end=''` estava sem espaço, então os números eram printados "grudados". Coloquei um espacinho ali pra ficar inteligível.

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para você criar uma nova `lista`, contendo os múltiplos de `3`, contidos inicialmente em uma outra lista, você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
meus_numeros = [1, 56, 342, 12, 781, 23, 43, 45, 123, 567]

multiplos_tres = list()
for c in meus_numeros:
    if c % 3 == 0:
        multiplos_tres.append(c)
multiplos_tres.sort()
print(f'\033[32mA lista dos múltiplos de "3" é: {multiplos_tres}')
```

Observe que este algoritmo varre a `lista inicial` e verifica se cada um dos elementos são múltiplos de `3`. Caso positivo, inseri na lista `multiplos_tres`.

Depois de ter inserido todos os possíveis múltiplos em `multiplos_tres`, o algoritmo ordena os valores e, em seguida, os exibe.

Agora, se você deseja `apenas exibir` os elementos da lista original que são múltiplos de `3`, Você pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
meus_numeros = [1, 56, 342, 12, 781, 23, 43, 45, 123, 567]

print(f'\033[32mOs múltiplos de "3" são:')
for c in meus_numeros:
    if c % 3 == 0:
        print(c, end='')
        print(', ' if c < meus_numeros[-1] else '.', end='')
```

Neste caso, o algoritmo varre a lista original e, caso o elemento seja múltiplo de `3`, exibe na tela.